# Can I ask GPG keyservers to name all keys signed by a particular key?

Tags: key-management, pgp

Given the alleged possibility that an adversary might attempt to acquire my (OFFLINE) Secret Certification Key and Passphrase and sign other keys with it, including a key they made with my User-Identity metadata to pretend to be me:

**Does GPG have a command that asks keyservers to search for and list every key signed by a particular key (fingerprint)?**

E.g., Is it possible to double check that I recognize every key signed by my key, 0x1234567890123456?

Maybe this isn't possible because it would make social graphing too easy, but all help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such command. But you could easily fetch a [dump of all keys known to the key servers](http://www.keysigning.org/sks/) and query it yourself someway. Or look at the [PGP Web of Trust statistics](http://pgp.cs.uu.nl/mk_path.cgi?STAT=A4FF2279&STATS=statistics) which includes such a list and grep it. The [underlying wot file](http://wot.christoph-egger.org/download/) could make things easier.